# Solve $\cos{x}>\sin{x}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm solving this trigonometric inequality

$$\sin{2x}+\cos{2x}\lt1$$
$$2\sin{x}\cos{x}+1+2\sin^2{x}\lt1$$
$$2\sin{x}(\cos{x}-\sin{x})\lt0$$
So this inequality is verified for

$$\sin{x}\gt0 \space\vee\cos{x}\gt\sin{x}$$

Any hints on how can I solve the last expression, $\cos{x}>\sin{x}$?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x) / \cos(x) = \tan(x)$.

Comment: What's your definition of trig functions? As Ennar said, you  could draw a picture, or use the series expansion

Comment: Use a picture of the unit circle. Where are the $x$-values greater than the $y$-values? Under the diagonal $y=x$.

Comment: I'm trying to find the solutions of the inequality, @YoTengoUnLCD. I think drawing a picture will help, I'm trying to figure out how.

Comment: As a matter of interest, what's your definition of trig function?

Comment: @PatrickStevens: ... but beware that $\cos x > \sin x$ is *not* equivalent to $1 > \tan x$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Certainly. But it is equivalent in certain regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions for $\sin x(\cos x-\sin x)<0$ are given by
$$
\sin x<0\quad\textit{and}\quad \cos x-\sin x>0\\[12px]
\textit{or}\\[8px]
\sin x>0\quad\textit{and}\quad \cos x-\sin x<0
$$
contrary to what you wrote.

The solutions for the first set become $\sin x<0$ and
$$
\cos x>\sin x
$$
that becomes $\cot x<1$ (because $\sin x<0$).

You can do similarly for the other set.

However, there's a better way. Recall that
$$
\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha=\sqrt{2}\cos(\alpha-\pi/4)
$$
so your inequality becomes
$$
\cos\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
that is, the unions of the intervals
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi<2x-\frac{\pi}{4}<\frac{7\pi}{4}+2k\pi
$$
which becomes
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi<2x<2\pi+2k\pi
$$
and, finally,
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi<x<\pi+k\pi
$$

---

Alternatively, use
$$
\sin2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x},\quad
\cos2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}
$$
and transform the inequality into
$$
2\tan x+1-\tan^2x<1+\tan^2x
$$
that should be easy. But be careful with the excluded angles (where $\tan x$ is undefined).

Answer (score 2):

Note that you get two kind of solutions for the inequality
$$\mbox{For}\;\sin(x)>0\;\mbox{and}\;\cos(x)<sin(x)$$
and 
$$\mbox{For}\;\sin(x)<0\;\mbox{and}\;\cos(x)>sin(x)$$
For the first one, you know that $\sin(x)>0$ if $0<x<\pi$ and $\cos(x)=\sin(x)$ for $x=\pi/4$. Then, for $\pi>x>\pi/4$ both conditions are fulfilled. However,
I encourage you to follow the same reasoning for the last case.

Comment: Thanks. Why are there two kinds of solutions (shouldn't it just be one)? And why did you write $\cos{x}<\sin{x}$ I'm not following, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was too fast. You know that $\sin x(\cos x-\sin x)<0$, meaning that or the sine is negative, or the expression inside the parenthesis is negative (one of the terms should be positive and the other is negative)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach to simplify the factors.

$$\begin{align}
2\sin x(\cos x-\sin x)
&=2\sqrt{2}\sin x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin x\right)\\
&=2\sqrt{2}\sin x\left(\cos(\pi/4)\cos x-\sin(\pi/4)\sin x\right)\\
&=2\sqrt{2}\sin x\cos(\pi/4+x)
\end{align}$$

So ultimately you are asking for when do $\sin x$ and $\cos(\pi/4+x)$ have the same sign.

$\sin(\pi/4+x)$ is positive when $0<x<\pi$.

$\cos(\pi/4+x)$ is positive when $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\frac{\pi}{4}+x<\frac{\pi}{2}\implies -\frac{3\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$.

So both are positive when $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$. I'll leave it to you to find when both are negative.

Answer (score 0):

Start from $\sin 2x + \cos 2x = \sqrt{2} \sin (2x + \frac{\pi}{4}) \lt 1$, then use the properties of the $\sin$ function.